# How to use Staticgenerator with Django + Apache + mod_python

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-python

I have currently an enviroment with Django + Apache via mod_python. How can I use [Staticgenerator](http://superjared.com/projects/static-generator/) without nginx, just with Apache and mod_python? Thank you.

Comment: Never heard of this. Worth looking into.

Comment: Are you not wanting to have a separate front-end http server, or are you just not wanting to use Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this page from the webfaction forum will help:

- http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=1945

Answer (score 0):

[Staticgenerator](http://superjared.com/projects/static-generator/) is designed to be used with a front-end http server. The example configuration as shown on the [Github Staticgenerator](http://github.com/JaredKuolt/staticgenerator) page is using [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) as the front-end http server and [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) as the back-end http server.

If you want a static website generator that isn't specifically designed to be used with a front-end http server, you might want to look at [Hyde](http://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde). [Hyde](http://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde) is Django powered and statically generates the webpages, which are then placed in a deploy directory. [Hyde](http://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde) came out of the developer, [Lakshmi Vyas](http://github.com/lakshmivyas/), wanting a Django based [Jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), which is a static website generator written in Ruby. Lakshmi Vyas did look into [Staticgenerator](http://superjared.com/projects/static-generator/) prior to developing [Hyde](http://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde) but decided to roll his own.

Comment: Apache is not just a "back end" server by any means. I work for a company that uses Apache as their front end server for over 45,000,000 per month.

Comment: @orokusaki: I was by no means implying that Apache is *just* a back-end server. I was simply citing the sample configuration of Staticgenerator, which uses Nginx as the front-end http server and Apache as the back-end http server.